# Can webkitGetUserMedia be true, but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, user-agent

I have detection browser code in JS app.
The first I check "navigator.webkitGetUserMedia" if it is true I try to find in user agent

```
userAgent.match(/chrome\/(\d+)\./).
```

But If I try to change user agent(to some mobile) by the chrome development tools, the navigator.webkitGetUserMedia is still true, but the user agent doesn't contain "chrome".

So, the question is Can we have a real mobile device with navigator.webkitGetUserMedia is true and user agent without "chrome"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like some pretty unstable browser detection.

Comment: If you are trying to do feature detection I would recommend looking into [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)

Comment: Not really possible to answer because any answer that might be correct today can become incorrect tomorrow. The user agent string is completely unreliable.